# My program is slowing down over time and i have no idea why. Memory leak?

Tags: c++, performance, memory-leaks

I'm working on a program that acts as a very simple voting system which reads numbers from a file, converts the numbers from the file to type unsigned int.

Here is an example of what data in the txt file looks like:

```
1 34 2 50 23 12
1 30 5 17
5
30 2 3 22
23 45
```

Each line is a vote from one person and the numbers on each line are the person's candidate preferences, left being first preference, right being last preference.

Once all the data is read from the file, it enters an infinite loop where every round (iteration) it calculates the remaining candidates (i.e. eliminates the candidate with the fewest votes). The program exits with code 0 when a candidate with the majority votes have been found.

My issue is that using the g++ compiler, at around round 40 or so the program starts to slow down and I'm assuming that this is because of a memory leak however I have no idea where in the program it could be leaking.

[This is what I get when debugging the program through Deleaker.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBN34.png)

**Note: Thank you, everyone, for your help. However, as much as I don't want to, I am required to redact the code posted here due to certain reasons. I will not delete the post in case someone can find use in the answers in some way. Hope you understand, thank you.**

Comment: This is a job for a debugger and/or a profiler. After compiling the program with the `-Og -g` options, a profiler (e.g. `perf`) will tell you where most of the time is spent. A debugger (e.g. `gdb`) allows you to interrupt the program at the problematic portion and step through the intructions one by one to see what is going differently than you expect. This is not likely to be a memory leak issue (you are not using `new` or anything like that). More likely is that your algorithm has unintended large runtime.

Comment: Also make sure that when not doing debugging, that you are using the `-O2` or `-O3` optimization flags to `g++`.

Comment: I see nothing that suggests a "memory leak". Everything uses containers. No `new` seen anywhere that would cause a leak. The shown code is on the big side, and needs to be analyzed; but it's more likely -- based on the given description -- to be a poor or inefficient algorithm.

Comment: there's a lot of allocation going on in your code. a lot of copying large objects.

Comment: I just realized, going by the image, that you are on windows. In that case my suggestions for profiler and debugger do not apply (i.e. `perf` and `gdb` don't work on windows). I don't know what the usual profiler and debugger on Windows are.

Comment: Every iteration (in `ranked_candidates()`) is creating a new map, copying data from that map to a vector, sorting that vector, then returning that vector.  While memory is not necessarily being leaked, there is a prime opportunity for memory fragmentation.

Comment: @uneven_mark - Memory fragmentation can happen even if the collection's size decreases over time.   That depends on how the allocator manages deallocation and subsequent reallocation - all it needs to do is delay a deallocation, and a subsequent allocation - even if smaller - can't be placed in that section of memory, hence fragmentation.   The erase loop you mention potentially does a similar thing (it won't generally increase the vector size either).

Comment: @Peter I didn't express myself well. The point I was trying to make is that there is probably more significant problems than memory fragmentation. I rewrote my comment into an answer.

Comment: _"I'm assuming that this is because of a memory leak"_ Why?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Using Deleaker and also the visual studio CRT library to dump memory leaks to console I saw a lot of memory leak messages so that's what I assumed. However, I'm still quite new to c++, only been learning it for around a few weeks so I'm still trying to get my head around some stuff. Apologies!

Comment: Ok - just trying to get you out of the habit of making an assumption then getting yourself buried in it!

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am making some guesses here, but in terms of time complexity of the algorithm,

```
while (p != vote_collection.end())  {
    //...
    if (p->spent()) {
        p = vote_collection.erase(p);
    }
 }
```

is problematic because `vote_collection` is a vector. Suppose `N` is that container's size, i.e. the number of votes. When `p->spent()` is true (which happens more likely in later iterations), then you are going to erase `p`. Erasing an element from a vector has linear time complexity in `N` in the worst case (when erasing at the beginning, which you are likely to do as you iterate the vector from beginning to end.) Since this will be happening to many of he votes, this loop has quadratic time complexity in `N`. You always want to try to avoid quadratic complexities if the input variable may be large.

The reason for this being the case is that vectors are storing the elements continuously in memory. When you erase an element, all the other elements after the erased one must be shifted one element to close up the gap. This requires moving almost the whole vector when the erased element is close to the beginning.

Instead of using the current approach, you could simply leave all the spent votes in the vector and simply make sure that `ranked_candidates` skips spent votes.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I will implement your suggestion and get back to you on how it works!

Comment: Great news! That's seemed to have worked! No more slowdowns towards the later rounds. I only have a small issue wherein the later rounds it will still read the number of votes to be 10000, for example, even though about 4000 of those entries are empty. This causes a problem in the calculation because I determine which candidate has the majority of votes based on the size of the vote_collection vector. Would there be a way to make vote_collection.size() exclude empty entires? Or could I just keep a tally where I do tally-- or ++ based on whether the current element is empty after .discard()?

Comment: @DWO No `std::vector` does offer such an option, but you can use a tally yourself as you say or you can write a function that iterates the vector and counts the non-spent entries or you can have a look at other containers for `vote_collection`. For example `std::list<vote>`, although that usually has bad memory access patterns. You can also resolve the issue with `std::vector` by replacing the vote that needs to be removed by the last vote in the vector and then reducing the size of the vector by one, since you are not really interested in the order of votes in the vector (I think).

Comment: In terms of vector order, they need to be ordered by the value in the <candidate, int> pair in descending order. But, obviously, the value is not unique like the key (candidate). So your last suggestion wouldn't work as I would then need to sort the vector again in descending order.

Comment: @DWO I am talking about the order of the `vote` objects inside `vote_collection`. You only form the `<candidate, int>` pairs locally in `ranked_candidates` and to form the counts the order of the `vote` objects inside `vote_collection` does not matter.

Comment: Ah, yes, my apologies, you're correct. In that case, your suggestion would work. That would also be a cleaner solution than using a tally haha.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @DWO Something else to consider is the `swap-and-pop` idiom. If order doesn't matter and you need to erase something from the middle, `std::swap` it with the element at the end, then call `std::vector::pop_back()`. This is faster because of `O(1)` complexity vs `std::vector::erase`'s `O(n)` linear complexity. It also avoids avoids having to shift every element past the erased element forward one which also incurs an additional assignment for each element after the erased one.

Comment: @Casey Thank you for this advice! I'll be sure to implement this. One question, would i still need to resize the array after `std::vector::pop_back()`?

Comment: @DWO No. `std::vector::pop_back` automatically resizes the vector.